# What is the most efficient way to run a large number of simple queries without overloading the db?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asynchronous, async-await

Let's say I have a method

```
public async Task SaveItemToDb(ItemEntity item) { ... }
```

which saves a single item the db and let's say I need to run it with 500,000 items and for business reasons I can't do bulk operations (e.g. I can't make a `SaveItemsToDb(IEnumerable<ItemEntity> items)`).

I'm wondering what the best way is to do this so that I don't overload the db with queries running simultaneously and yet each query can be considered independent of each other. Is this the case for `Task.WhenAll(...)`?

Comment: One way to help the db is to compile all the queries to one block and execute it.

Comment: @ShemeerBK Can you elaborate?

Comment: Hi ,I am not sure if i get your scenario right,In my previous project ,I had a problem like this whrereby I had to run
insert statements for each created object .And the problem was that ,at the data layer everytime the connection
was opened , the query was executed and the connection was closed after that. That dragged the insert operation 
for some time. The simple work around was to collect all those insert querries in a class and to execute in blocks
of 100 with a timer. May be it helps your case.

Comment: Re-examine the business reasons. You already know the correct solution - it's to run fewer but more complex queries, so that the database can amortise its transaction costs across more work.

Comment: Anything related to efficiency results in a speculative argument that cannot be resolved without measurement. Inserting half a million rows is a _bulk operation_, i.e. your doing a bulk operation like it or not. If you are concerned about _overloading_ the database then you need to conduct load testing in your environment. Guessing without measurement is not the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

You could make sure you have at most `numTasks` running. The tricky bit at the end is to make sure you wait till all the tasks have finished. Unfortunately [CountDownEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent(v=vs.110).aspx) does not have an async version so it is blocking but maybe that is not a big deal.

The code below doesn't handle the errors in any of the tasks correctly. You may want to improve it.

```
async Task ProcessTasks(IEnumerable<Task> tasks, int numTasks){
    var count = new CountDownEvent(0);
    SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(numTasks);
    foreach(var task in tasks){
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        task.ContinueWith(_=>{
            semaphore.Release();
            count.Signal();
            }
        );
    }
    count.Wait(); // Wait till the count reaches zero
}
```